# Add permanent SSL exception for expired certificate in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, https

I tried to add a SSL exception according to [these insctructions](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-permanent-ssl-certificate-exception-chrome-andrey-batyrenko/):

1. Export current certificate as file (*.cer)
2. Import it under *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*

After I restart Chrome 78 I don't see the before imported certificate. In the console I still get the following error

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

How can I make an exception in Chrome for one site?

Comment: Don't add random certificates to your Trusted Root.

Comment: @VarunAgw: Thanks for the hint. It's not a random certificate. It's from a company intern website and I don't want to wait until it is fixed.

Comment: I think Firefox allow adding exceptions. Is it acceptable to you?

Comment: Now I tried Firefox, but there isn't a button for adding an exception anymore ...